# Creating colormap at specific point and color weights at matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

i have some datas which are included some deflection and force values. Like deltaX deltaY and forces measured at that points as Fx and Fy. I want to create a colormap at that points with the magnitude of forces and color transition between points in 2D. For example if point1 is red(high value, big deflection) and point2 is blue(low value, small deflection) i want color transition between them. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Data are given below.
First column positionX
second column positionY
third column forceX
forth column forceY

I need to plot this map according to X and Y positions and force magnitudes.

***When i take the magnitude of vectors we have positionX positionY and only 1 force value.

```
filein =

         0         0   -0.0395    0.1189
         0    1.5053    0.2127  -11.3568
   -0.0008    3.0082    0.6719  -22.0470
   -0.0048    4.5093    0.9231  -32.7004
    0.0069    6.0033    1.2499  -43.2750
   -0.0029    7.5008    1.6960  -53.4941
    1.4981    0.0102   -1.5213    1.2031
    1.4979    1.5003   -1.2326  -10.0738
    1.5071    3.0043   -0.6965  -20.7386
    1.4896    4.4943   -0.2563  -31.5026
    1.5020    5.9921    0.0480  -42.3186
    1.5021    7.4909    0.7614  -52.7354
    3.0016    0.0022   -2.6099    1.9455
    3.0022    1.4960   -2.6157   -9.3388
    2.9959    3.0087   -1.8898  -20.1823
    2.9955    4.4977   -1.3670  -30.7842
    2.9923    6.0041   -0.8444  -41.7370
    2.9976    7.5055   -0.2241  -52.1361
    4.4995   -0.0016   -4.0576    2.5489
    4.5009    1.4961   -3.8135   -8.6871
    4.4930    2.9939   -3.0315  -19.4825
    4.4986    4.5045   -2.6034  -30.2974
    4.5046    5.9931   -1.9570  -40.9145
    4.4972    7.5023   -1.1994  -51.4071
    5.9931   -0.0014   -5.1986    3.2395
    5.9954    1.5000   -5.1224   -7.9289
    6.0017    2.9977   -4.3153  -18.7471
    6.0045    4.4939   -3.6613  -29.4662
    6.0030    6.0081   -2.9086  -40.3400
    6.0003    7.5006   -2.1704  -50.6973
    7.4974   -0.0018   -6.5690    4.0048
    7.4977    1.5043   -6.5230   -7.0994
    7.5047    3.0058   -5.5833  -18.0435
    7.5083    4.5058   -4.8070  -28.6861
    7.5024    6.0059   -4.0150  -39.4321
    7.5006    7.5023   -3.1837  -49.8617
```

Comment: This is a 4D matrix that cannot be represented as a 3D surface. Why don't you consider plotting two separate figures a `X,Y,Fx` and a `X,Y,Fy`?

Comment: Actually when i take the magnitude of vectors we have 3 different parameter.

Comment: Its like at certain points color weights. For example we have a blue surface or something like that. When it gets the force data according to data program will paint a certain area with a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `meshgrid` and `surf` or `mesh` command to plot it:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(filein(:,1),filein(:,2));
M = sqrt(filein(:,3).^2+filein(:,4).^2);
Z=meshgrid(M,M);
C = gradient(Z);
figure
surf(X,Y,Z,C);colorbar
```

[image]

You can remove the mesh and interpolate as follows:

```
surf(X, Y, Z,'EdgeColor', 'None', 'facecolor', 'interp');
```

[image]

Then view it from above:

```
view(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Its supposed to be in 2D. when i change it to look from X-Y plane. it is what i would like to see. But colors are so close each other when i look from X-Y. How can i make it more evident?

Comment: Thank you. I can handle after this point with playing on it a bit. U gave me a great start point. Cheers..

Comment: Sure. No problem.